# Google App Engine's data viewer for java is not showing utf8 char correctly

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I can access the data viewer
http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/

but the UTF-8 characters are always displayed as question marks?

I could write UTF-8 and read back from the datastore into my web page as UTF-8 (because I've included all the tags).  It's just annoying (misleading) that the data viewer displays a `?` when it's really in UTF-8 inside?

Can someone tell me if there's something I should fix regarding the data viewer setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug with the local data viewer. If you're positive that your text is encoded in UTF-8 (and not another codec), please file a bug on the issue tracker.